# Why in RxAndroid using compose running in main thread while using map running in io thread?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have this piece of code you can see when I am using map for the transformation the currentThread is background thread while I am using compose() it is in main thread .
Why it works this way and I could not find document about this.

```
public Single<Content> fetchContent() {
    return mEndpoint.content(id);
}


public Single<Content> fetchContent() {
    return mEndpoint.fetchContent()
            .map(content -> {
                Log.i("thread-name", "map" + Thread.currentThread());
                return content;
            })
            .compose(content -> {
                Log.i("thread-name", "compose" + Thread.currentThread());
                return content;
            });
}

//thread-name: compose. Thread[main,5,main]
//thread-name: map. Thread[OkHttp ...,10,main]
```

Comment: The `compose` function is called/evaluated at creation, not subscription, thus this was called on the main thread, and why it logs immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure if I understand the answer.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#some-terminology

Comment: Is it possible to  have transformation in compose and in background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments `compose` will execute the lambda right away and therefore the print statement is ran on the main thread.

However, the argument to `compose` is actually the observable that will emit the `content` and not the content itself. So you actually want to operate on this just like a normal observable. Here's, for example, a map function that will not run on the main thread:

```
mEndpoint.fetchContent()
        .map(content -> {
            Log.i("thread-name", "map" + Thread.currentThread());
            return content;
        })
        .compose(content -> content.map(it -> {
           Log.i("thread-name", "map" + Thread.currentThread());

           return it;
        }))
```

Note that I've kept the variable name `content` the same so you can see the differences easily, but it should actually be more like this:

```
.compose(obs -> obs.map(content -> {
           Log.i("thread-name", "map" + Thread.currentThread());

           return content;
        }))
```

One last thing, I usually use compose when I have several operations that I can apply to an observable and reuse them in other chains. For simple mappings I usually stick to `map` and friends.